# I lost my backup sim card so i can't able to open my gmail.?

Tags: gmail

I Can't sign in my gmail account. Because am enabled 2-steps verification but i lost my sim card . how can I open my gmail account without my backup phone .? please help me..

Answer (score 0):

When you enabled two step authentication, you should have received a set of backup codes that you can use to log in when you lose access to your account.

If you do not have those codes, or if you didn't receive them, you should ask your cellular provider for another SIM card, although your provider may ask money to send you another SIM card.